# Is the free abelian group of rank 2 linear?

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory

Is the group $\mathbb{Z}^2$ linear? By linear I mean There is a injective homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to $GL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ for some nonnegative interger $n.$ 
I tried the following homomorphism f which sends the two geneartors $c$ and $d$ of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ to the matrices $C$ and $D$ where
$C=\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 2     & 0      & \cdots       & \cdots      & 0  \\
0  & 1 & \ddots & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\vdots  & \vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &   0     & \cdots  & \cdots  & 1 & 2 \\
0 & 0      & \cdots        & \cdots      & 0      & 1
\end{pmatrix}$ and $D=\begin{pmatrix}
1  & 3     & 0      & \cdots       & \cdots      & 0  \\
0  & 1 & \ddots & \ddots &        & \vdots \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \ddots & \ddots & \vdots    \\
\vdots  & \vdots &  & \ddots & \ddots & 0  \\
0  &   0     & \cdots  & \cdots  & 1 & 3 \\
0 & 0      & \cdots        & \cdots      & 0      & 1
\end{pmatrix}.$

Comment: (1) What do you mean by "linear"? (Do you perhaps mean "orderable"?) (2) What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: Linear as in admitting a faithful finite-dimensional representation? Well, what do you thiink about the problem?

Comment: The homomorphism I tried is not injective for $n=2.$ That's why I'm stuck. I don't know how to make this homomorphism injective.

Comment: The homomorphism you tried is injective for $n \ge 3$, but there are much easier homomorphisms.

Comment: Could you give me a hint to prove the injectivity please?

Answer (score 2):

Using different primes such as $2$ and $3$ would be a promising idea on the diagonal where things naturally *multiply*, but that would require you to work over $\mathbb Q$ to keep your matrices invertible. Off the diagonal, the tendency is for things to *add*, and there primes won't help you.

A product of groups naturally corresponds to a direct sum of representations, so block matrices are the tool you need. The most straightforward mapping would be
$$ (a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & a & & \\ 0 & 1 & & \\ && 1 & b & \\ && 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} $$
but you can save a dimension by unifying the preserved rows:
$$ (a,b)\in\mathbb Z^2 \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} 1 & & a \\  & 1 & b \\ && 1 \end{pmatrix} $$